# AntiVirus for OSX running parallels

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, anti-virus, vmware-fusion, parallels

I'm using OS X 10.10.1 on my Mac. I use Parallels Desktop 10 and VMware Fusion 7.1. I do use windows a lot on Parallels and Fusion (Several Virtual machines). Windows 8.1,7 and XP. I've installed Avast free AV on OS X. Do i need to install separate Anti viruses on VMs ?? or do OS X Avast antivirus detect Windows viruses and malware ? Please explain. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Avist would not be able to go into an OS package. Try installing Microsoft Security Essentials. Here is the link. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=168949 it is a free antivirus now provided by Windows OR you can try running AVG free which can be found at http://free.avg.com/

Comment: MSE not supported on W8.1

Answer (score 0):

Almost all malware on a VM can not affect your computer directly unless you have enabled some integration features from your VM software such as sharing files between your Mac and virtual PC.

Of course, you should still worry about malware on your VMs, to prevent people from stealing your information and infecting other computers, either on your network, or on the internet.

You should definitely install antivirus software on Windows, especially if you're running Windows XP. Windows XP is no longer updated by Microsoft so there are lots of malwares that can infect it.

Microsoft has their own antivirus software called [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download), but there is also some [high quality third party antivirus software](http://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/).